# Swift cannot append to subscript?

Tags: swift

I can't seem to use .append() on a subscript.

For example, here's the array:

```
var arrayTest = [
  "test": 8,
  "test2": 4,
  "anotherarry": [
    "test4": 9
  ]
]
```

I am able to do this:

```
arrayTest.append(["test3": 3])
```

But I can't append to the array inside arrayTest. This is what I'm trying:

```
arrayTest["anotherarray"].append(["finaltest": 2])
```

Answer (score 2):

First note: your variable `arrayTest` is a dictionary of type `[String: NSObject]`, not an array. Similarly the value for the key `anotherarray` is also a dictionary.

Second note: you are setting the key `anotherarry` and retrieving the key `anotherarray` which would be nil in this example.

I'm also not sure how you are able to call `append()` on `arrayTest` since it is a dictionary and doesn't have that method.

But the key issue with what you are trying to do is that dictionaries and arrays are value types and are copied when passed around, rather than referenced. When you subscript `arrayTest` to get `anotherarray`, you are getting a *copy* of the value, not a reference to the value inside the dictionary.

If you want to modify something directly inside an array or dictionary (as opposed to replacing it), that something *must* be a reference type (a class).  Here's an example of how your code could be accomplished:

```
var arrayTest = [
    "test": 8,
    "test2": 4,
    "anotherarray": ([
        "test4": 9
    ] as NSMutableDictionary)
]

(arrayTest["anotherarray"] as? NSMutableDictionary)?["test5"] = 10
```

Note that this code forces "anotherarray" to explicitly be an `NSMutableDictionary` (a class type from Objective-C) instead of defaulting to a Swift dictionary (a value type). That's what makes it possible to modify it from outside the dictionary, since it is now being passed as a reference and not copied.

### Further Note:

As pointed out in the comments, using NSMutableDictionary is not something I personally recommend and isn't a pure Swift solution, it's just the way to arrive at a working example with the fewest changes to your code.

Your other options would include replacing the `anotherarray` value entirely with a modified copy instead of trying to subscript it directly, or if it's important for you to be able to chain your subscripts, you could create a class wrapper around a Swift dictionary like this:

```
class DictionaryReference<Key:Hashable, Value> : DictionaryLiteralConvertible, CustomStringConvertible {

    private var dictionary = [Key : Value]()

    var description: String {
        return String(dictionary)
    }

    subscript (key:Key) -> Value? {
        get {
            return dictionary[key]
        }
        set {
            dictionary[key] = newValue
        }
    }

    required init(dictionaryLiteral elements: (Key, Value)...) {
        for (key, value) in elements {
            dictionary[key] = value
        }
    }
}
```

Then you would use it similarly to the NSMutableDictionary example:

```
var arrayTest = [
    "test": 8,
    "test2": 4,
    "anotherarray": ([
        "test4": 9
    ] as DictionaryReference<String, Int>)
]

(arrayTest["anotherarray"] as? DictionaryReference<String, Int>)?["test5"] = 10
```

Comment: I would avoid suggesting the use of `NSObject` and `NSMutableDictionary` classes in Swift. They belong to Objective-C and do work in Swift only for backward compatibility reasons. For sure they do not represent the Swifty way of doing things.

Comment: @appzYourLife  Yeah, I agree and I'm not recommending it, but it's arguably the shortest route to converting the poster's existing code to a working example. I'll add a note at the end of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

> For example, here's the array:

Nope, `arrayTest` is NOT an array. It's a dictionary.

> I am able to do this...

No you're not. There is no such `append` method into a dictionary.

### The problem

So it looks like you have a dictionary like this

```
var dict: [String:Any] = [
    "test": 8,
    "test2": 4,
    "anotherdict": ["test4": 9]
]
```

You want to change the array inside the key `anotherdict` (yes I renamed your key) in order to add the following key/value pair

```
"finaltest": 2
```

Here's the code

```
if var anotherdict = dict["anotherdict"] as? [String:Int] {
    anotherdict["finaltest"] = 2
    dict["anotherdict"] = anotherdict
}
```

Result

```
[
    "test2": 4,
    "test": 8,
    "anotherdict": ["test4": 9, "finaltest": 2]
]
```